# Using Redux with React v0.12.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, redux, react-redux

I want to use [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) in a React (v0.12.2) based project. However Redux is much newer than React and mainly supports only latest versions of it.

Is there a version of Redux that would work? If no one would, what could be the alternative state container library to use with this version of React, without ES6 syntax?

Comment: Any particular reason you are using such an outdated version of react?

Comment: are you referring to redux or react-redux (Redux bindings for react) ? And why to not use React 15?

Comment: You can use Redux without its custom bindings for React, although I can't imagine why you would want to as opposed to just using a newer version of React.

Comment: It's a big project with lots of components and adapting it to a newer version would be quite troublesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook codebase has more than 20,000 components, and it keeps up with React updates. I’d suggest at least giving updates a try. Make sure that rather than jump from 0.12 to latest, you upgrade one version at a time, so you can react to the deprecation warnings. Also check out [react-codemod](https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod) that lets you automate some of the changes.

That said you can totally use Redux in an older projects, just without React Redux. You can use the store API directly, `subscribe()` from your components, and use `getState()` to read the current state. Or you can fork React Redux and try to get it to work with 0.12.